# Non-editable text box in wxPython

Tags: python, textbox, wxpython, wxwidgets

How to create a non-editable text box with no cursor in wxPython to dump text in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wx.StaticText`

You could also use a regular TextCtrl with the style `TE_READONLY` but that shows a cursor and the text looks editable, but it isn't.

Comment: @tom10, thanks, TE_READONLY is what I'm looking for. Do you know how to dynamically add text there?

Comment: Glad to help.  `myctrl.AppendText("new text")` will append text.  (Making it non-editable will still allow changes to the text by the program, btw.)