# scrollbar for statictext in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, scrollbar

is possible to add a scrollbar to a statictext in wxpython?

the thing is that i'm creating this statictext:

```
self.staticText1 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_FRAME1STATICTEXT1,label=u'some text here',name='staticText1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(16, 96),
                                size=wx.Size(408, 216),style=wx.ST_NO_AUTORESIZE | wx.THICK_FRAME | wx.ALIGN_CENTRE | wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
    self.staticText1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
    self.staticText1.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_SYSTEM)
    self.staticText1.SetFont(wx.Font(9, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, False,u'MS Shell Dlg 2'))
    self.staticText1.SetAutoLayout(True)
    self.staticText1.SetConstraints(LayoutAnchors(self.staticText1, False,True, True, False))
    self.staticText1.SetHelpText(u'')
```

but later i use StaticText.SetLabel to change the label and the new text is too big to fit the window, so i need to add a scrollbar to the statictext..

i tried adding wx.VSCROLL to the style, and the scrollbar show up but cant scroll down to see the rest of the text..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wx.StaticText` is designed to never respond to mouse events and never take user focus.  Given that this is its role in life, it seems that a scrollbar would be inconsistent with its purpose.

There are two ways to get what you want:  **1)** You could use a regular `TextCtrl` with the style TE_READONLY (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254819/non-editable-text-box-in-wxpython)); or **2)** you could make a scrolled window that contains your `StaticText` control.